# How to remove lines containing IP address?

Tags: text-processing, sed, ip-address

I have a file like:

```
http://example.mx
https://test.com
http://4.3.4.4
http://dev.somedomain.com
http://1.3.4.2
```

I want to get rid of the ones with IPs so that the result should be:

```
http://example.mx
https://test.com
http://dev.somedomain.com
```

What I did is:

```
cat  in.log |  sed  '/^http:\/\/[0-9]/d'  > out.log
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Any specific reason to use `cat in.log | ... ` and not e.g. ` ... | cat > out.log` or `.... | cat | cat | cat | cat > out.log`. `cat` is not necessary here, you can use `< in.log` and with `sed` you can also specify the input file as a commandline argument ( `sed 's//^http:\/\/[0-9]/d' in.log > out.log` )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But it *does* work.   The correct answer appears to be already in your question.

```
$ cat in.log
http://example.mx
https://test.com
http://4.3.4.4
http://dev.somedomain.com
http://1.3.4.2
$ cat  in.log |  sed  '/^http:\/\/[0-9]/d'  > out.log
$ cat out.log
http://example.mx
https://test.com
http://dev.somedomain.com
$
```

Comment: Oh my bad. I had an unseen space at the begining of each line on original file!

Comment: It is bad advice to create an extra process with `cat` and pip the output thereof to `sed`. You can specify the input file to `sed` on the commandline: `sed '/^http:\/\/[0-9]/d' in.log > out.log` and even if that was not the case you should not use `cat`, but use `< in.log sed '/^http:\/\/[0-9]/d' in.log > out.log`

Comment: sure, agree.  was keeping with the approach suggested by the OP, which was perfectly functional, albeit used a 'useless cat' etc.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want to remove *lines* in your input. In addition to `sed`, there’s a very simple solution using `grep -v`:

```
grep -v 'http://\([0-9]\+\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\+' in.log
```

Furthermore, there’s no need for `cat` and the pipe here either way: `cat foo | bar` can be replaced by `bar < foo` in general, and in this particular instance you can just pass the filename as an argument to either `grep` or `sed` without the need for the pipe.

Shell purists will generally frown on this use of `cat` because it’s unnecessarily starting a separate process (and because `cat`’s purpose is to con*cat*enate files …).

Comment: removing line based on simple pattern can be made by either sed, grep, perl or awk.

Comment: @Archemar Yeah, I’m going to change the wording. In fact I wanted to show an alternative, not The One True Solution.

Comment: I actually love using `grep -v` with regex

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the lines from `in.log`, you can use the `-i` flag of `sed`:

```
sed -i '/^http:\/\/[0-9]/d' in.log
```

Answer (score 2):

this already work, however
`/^http:\/\/[0-9]/` will match

```
http://1.hello.word
```

to match "full IP" use `/^http:\/\/[0-9\.]*$/`

where

- `[0-9\.]` match digit and dot ...
- `*` ... 0 or more time ..
- `$` ... till end of line.